# Ask for recommendation for the books about rough set theory

Tags: set-theory

I am a graduate student of Shanxi Normal University in China and I'm very interested in the rough set theory.However,I cannot find some good books about this set.So,I want to get some information by MO.Thank you very much.

Comment: Definitions, at least, are here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_set